Can I animate a Poly3DCollection in matplotlib with blit=True
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation
import matplotlib.animation as animation

figure = plt.figure()
axis3d = figure.add_subplot(projection="3d")

class Animator:
    POINTS = [(0, -1, -1), (0, 1, -1), (0, 1, 1), (0, -1, 1)]

    def __init__(self):
        axis3d.set_xlim3d(-2, 2)
        axis3d.set_ylim3d(-2, 2)
        axis3d.set_zlim3d(-2, 2)
        axis3d.set(xlabel="X", ylabel="Y", zlabel="Z")
        self.poly = axis3d.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection([self.POINTS], color='black'))

    def frame(self, i):
        # slowly tilting rotation
        rotation = Rotation.from_euler("ZY", [i, i/40], degrees=True)
        rotated_points = rotation.apply(self.POINTS)
        self.poly.set_verts([rotated_points])
        # return graph objects that have been modified
        return [self.poly]

    @staticmethod
    def run(blit=False):
        animator = Animator()
        animator.animation = animation.FuncAnimation(
            fig=figure, func=animator.frame, interval=3, blit=blit)
        plt.show()

Animator.run()
# Animator.run(blit=True)

When I run the code with blit=False, it works just fine and I get the expected rotating square. When I run the code with blit=True, I get an empty axis with no square.
Does FuncAnimation just not know how to handle a Poly3DCollection when blit is set? It doesn't complain about my returning it from the frame function as a "modified graph object".
